# django import module from sibling app directory

Tags: import, django-1.9

I have Django Project with the following structure

```
src/
  apps/
    __init__.py
    app_name/
      ...
      serializers.py
      __init__.py
      ...
  project_name/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    static/
    templates/
    urls.py
    utils.py
    wsgi.py
```

and I have the following in settings

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
path.append(BASE_DIR)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))
```

how can I import utils.py from serializers.py ?

Comment: `BASE_DIR` seems to be `src` in your case and `PROJECT_ROOT` is the parent dir of `src`. I think you want to join 'apps' to `BASE_DIR` instead of `PROJECT_ROOT`. Print out the values of these variables just to make sure... In your case it seems that import should work with `from project_name import utils` given that you set the path correctly. However I wouldn't put utilities used by apps into the project folder. Instead create an app or package called "core", "common" or "utils" in your apps directory to store your utility stuff.

Comment: PROJECT_ROOT is src directory I've checked with log
BASE_DIR is project_name
the reason I have included utils in project folder 
that I wil use it for all apps 
any suggestion please ?

Comment: you are right os.path.dirname is a mistake 
I've created base App to store utilities It's seems best practice
thanks pasztorpisti